# Where can I learn about the low level concepts used in a Graphic design application?

Tags: color, gimp

I am new to Graphics design. I want to learn a graphics design software in order to develop a game. I chose Gimp as it was free and i followed few tutorials. Most tutorials accomplished the goal  without explaining low level concepts such as different blend modes, color terms such as threshold, levels, etc. Where can I find detailed explanations about these? If possible provide free resources. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For example at [Gimp Documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/)

http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html e.g. has examples of all layer modes

> GIMP has twenty-one layer modes. Layer modes are also sometimes called “blending modes”. Selecting a layer mode changes the appearance of the layer or image, based on the layer or layers beneath it. If there is only one layer, the layer mode has no effect. There must therefore be at least two layers in the image to be able to use layer modes.
>
> You can set the layer mode in the Mode menu in the Layers dialog. GIMP
>   uses the layer mode to determine how to combine each pixel in the top
>   layer with the pixel in the same location in the layer below it. ...

Unless you are asking for more conceptual things, the manual will help with most of your questions.